# Mobx-state-tree Clone also changes the original item?

Tags: mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I have the following model snippet:

```
nodeOrigin: types.maybe(types.reference(nodeState)),
node: types.maybe(nodeState),
```

And I start editing a node by the following function (the original node i saved so it can be used in a undo() function):

```
startEditing(node) {
    self.nodeOrigin = node;
    self.node = clone(node);
}
```

And in my render method the editing node is used like this:

```
<form className="form">
     <TextField margin='dense' value={getStore().node["name"]} />
</form>
```

But when I change the name and print the content of both the node and the original node, they have both the changed name. NodeOriginal should contain the original name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider creating an interactive piece at https://codesandbox.io/dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`types.reference` [is tied to](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#references-and-identifiers) `types.identifier`. The thing you probably misunderstand here, is that `types.reference` references the `types.identifier` property of the given node and not the node itself.

When you `clone` you do not alter an `id` of the original node. `types.reference` is resolved on the fly from identifier cache by the given `id`, so *it will* always reference the node with the given `id`.

Moreover, given that id cannot be altered after initialization and that it should be unique across the whole node tree, I'd conclude that nodes having `types.identifier` property are not meant to be cloned with `clone` utility.

Alternatively, you could take a snapshot of the node you want to clone, manually update `types.identifier` property and create a new node from that. Something like:

```
const cloneWithNewId = (node, id) =>
      getType(node).create(Object.assign({}, getSnapshot(node), { id }));
```

Comment: Hmmm, your last suggestion doesn't work, what I do: getSnapshot(self.node).id = 123 and that results in: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '#<Object>'. Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: `getSnapshot` produces a frozen object, so instead of changing it directly, create a new one: `Object.assign({}, getSnapshot(node), { id: 'new id })`